# Sass in command line get output

Tags: php, css, sass

I'm currently working on a webtool which provide a bunch of utilities for webdesigners, and i have one whose role is to read uploaded Sass and Less file and return plain CSS. For Sass, my solution is to run in PHP `exec('sass input.scss output.css')`

But this force me to save sass input in a file, and get the output in a file, extract file content as string and unlink files when it's done... It's a lot of unnecessary ressources used. What i want is to have to possibility to give the sass command line a string as input, and get a string as the output. The doc say nothing about it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do not specify output file, and precise the second argument of `exec()` to retrieve the output:

```
exec('sass input.scss', $output);
```

#### Direct input

You can try the `-s` argument of the sass command line to avoid the creation of a temporary file.
But when I use it in command line, I have to type this:

```
$ sass --scss -s <<"EOF"
> .clever {
>   font-weight: bold;
>   .age { font-variant: small-caps; }
>}
> EOF
.clever {
  font-weight: bold; }
  .clever .age {
    font-variant: small-caps; }
```

Comment: This is great, i wasn't expecting so much. No solution to give string input instead of file ? If not, your solution is still way better than mine, i'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamS I updated my answer. If you'll take it, thx to validate the answer ;)